# Can't get BODY in POST request

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, web

I have a HTML file served from my NodeJS server, where I am trying to pass the details of the form to the backend. But for some weird reason on making the POST request, I am not getting any body. Whenever I am printing the `req.BODY` in my console, all I am getting is `undefined`.

The HTML page-

```
<form action="/login" method="POST">
    <div class="container-fluid ">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3"></div>
            <div class="col-md-6 bg-light p-5">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-3"></div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label class="form-label col-label" for="fname">First Name</label>
                        <input class="field__input" type="text" name="fname" placeholder="" id="#fname">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3"></div>
                    <div class="col-md-3"></div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label class="form-label col-label" for="lname">Last Name</label>
                        <input class="field__input" type="text" name="lname" placeholder="" id="#lname">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3"></div>
                    <div class="col-md-3"></div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label class="form-label col-label my-3" for="email">Email Address</label>
                        <input class="field__input" type="text" name="email" placeholder="joe.black@gmail.com" id="#email">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3"></div>
                    <div class="col-md-3"></div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label class="form-label col-label" for="pass">Password </label>
                        <input class="field__input" type="password" name="pass" placeholder="" id="#pass">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3"></div>

                </div>
                <div class="form-group text-center">
                    <input id="#create" type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-outline-dark" >
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </form>
```

My NodeJS route-

```
router.post('/login', async (req, res) => {
    // const user = User(req.body);
    try {
        console.log(req.body);
        res.status(201).send({});
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
        res.status(500).send('ERROR');
    }
});
```

All my terminal is printing is

```
undefined
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Did you use `express.json()` and `express.urlencoded({ extended: true })` middlewares?

Comment: I had not included them, but even after I have. There is no difference howsoever

Comment: I am still getting undefined

Comment: @DimaParzhitsky your solution worked!! Can you pl tell me the role of the 2 lines that you asked me to add??

Comment: These are middlewares designed specifically to parse requests' body ([`express.json`](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#express.json) and [`express.urlencoded`](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#express.urlencoded))